# ionic2: facebook album cover photo

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic2

I am able to fetch all the albums from Facebook User's account. I am trying to show it in Grid but I need cover photo of Album as well. I tried below code:

```
<ion-grid>
    <div *ngFor="let album of albums; let i = index;">
        <ion-row *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
            <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="i < albums.length">
                <ion-card>
                    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{albums[i].id}}/picture?type=album" />
                    <div class="card-title">{{ albums[i].name }}</div>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="i+1 < albums.length">
                <ion-card (click)="albumClicked(album)">
                    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{albums[i+1].id}}/picture?type=album" />
                    <div class="card-title">{{ albums[i+1].name }}</div>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="i+2 < albums.length">
                <ion-card (click)="albumClicked(album)">
                    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{albums[i+2].id}}/picture?type=album" />
                    <div class="card-title">{{ albums[i+2].name }}</div>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
</ion-grid>
```

This is how I get albums:

**FacebookService.ts:**

```
...
getUserAlbums(userID) {
    return this.facebook.api("/v2.9/" + userID + "/albums", []);
}
...
```

**FacebookAlbumsPage.ts:**

```
...
getUserAlbums(facebookUserId) {
    this.showLoading();
    this.facebookUserDetails.getUserAlbums(facebookUserId).then((res) => {
        this.albums = res.data;
        this.hideLoading();
    });
}
...
```

While getting image I get below error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

Does anyone know how to get facebook albums with their cover photos using Ionic2 ?

**Edit:**
This is the url that is passed in img src:

https://graph.facebook.com/186028675250734/picture?type=album

But when I opened the link directly into browser, it returned below error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '186028675250734' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "BtQDS1csSgu"
   }
}
```

Comment: Debugging step 1: Call one of those image URLs you are creating directly in your browser, and see what you get.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the question on your comment.

Comment: See, no sufficient permission to make that API request, resp. view that content. Album cover photos are not publicly available, that is for profile cover photos only. If you append your access token as a parameter, you should get to see the image. // You need to get the CDN URL of the image via API, so you need to go via the cover_photo field first.